# Why isn't DownThemAll able to recognize my reddit URL regular expression?

Tags: regex

So I'm trying to download all my old reddit posts using a combination of AutoPagerize and DownThemAll.

Here are two sample URLs I want to distinguish between:

- http://www.reddit.com/r/China/comments/kqjr1/what_is_the_name_of_this_weird_chinese_medicine/c2med97
- http://www.reddit.com/r/China/comments/kqjr1/what_is_the_name_of_this_weird_chinese_medicine/c2meana?context=3

The regexp I'm trying to use is this: (\b)http://www.reddit.com/([^?\s]*)?

I want all my reddit posts downloaded, but I don't want any redundancy, so I want to match all of my reddit posts except for anything with a question mark (after which there's a "context=3" character).

I've used RegEx Buddy to show that the regexp fits the first URL but not the second one. However, DownThemAll does not recognize this. Is DownThemAll's ability to parse regexp limited, or am I doing something wrong?

---

For now, I've just decided to download them all, but to use a renaming mask of `*subdirs*.*text*.*html*` so that I can later mass remove anything containing the word "context" in its filename.

Comment: In my experience, quite a few regex engines don't support "named" character classes like `\s` within a `[` ... `]` range.

Comment: Oh - thanks for the info! Unfortunately, I found another regexp where I could remove the \s, but it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Oh - that's just because a lot of RegexBuddy scripts use \b at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

Reddit does have an API, you might want to take a look at that instead, might be easier.

https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API

EDIT: Looks like `http://www.reddit.com/user/USERNAME/.json` might be what you want